# Convert a tuple into a custom string

Tags: python

I am facing a situation

this is a class for an example

```
class SearchCustomerLocators:

    txtEmail_id = (By.ID, "SearchEmail")
    txtFirstName_id = (By.ID,"SearchFirstName")
    txtLastName_id = (By.ID,"SearchLastName")
    btnSearch_id = (By.ID,"search-customers")
```

so when I called custom function  ...

```
self.click(*SearchCustomerLocators.txtEmail_xpath)
```

click function as below

```
def click(self, webelement):
    #self._driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", webelement)
    el = self._wait.until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable(webelement))
    self._highlight_element(el, "green")
    el.click()
```

The Problem is the Click function expects only 1 argument as full string **('xpath', "//button[@type='submit']")**

but the *SearchCustomerLocators.txtEmail_xpath is returning the string as with
**xpath //button[@type='submit']**

how to can I manipulate the string to get the custom output?

when i try to manipulate this x = *SearchCustomerLocators.txtEmail_xpath
i am getting the error as `Can't use starred expression here`

Comment: Where does SearchCustomerLocators.txtEmail_xpath come from? Your class definition doesn't show it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you just need to remove the `*` from:

```
self.click(*SearchCustomerLocators.txtEmail_xpath)
```

To be:

```
self.click(SearchCustomerLocators.txtEmail_xpath)
```

Below is a simple example script to click on the "Ask Question" button on this page. Note that I would not personally set things up this way but I was attempting to replicate the functionality you posted above.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
import sys
sys.path.append('D:\\Path\\to\\your\\geckodriver.exe')
service = Service('D:\\Path\\to\\your\\geckodriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service)

class SearchCustomerLocators:
    txtEmail_id = (By.ID, "SearchEmail")
    txtFirstName_id = (By.ID,"SearchFirstName")
    txtLastName_id = (By.ID,"SearchLastName")
    btnSearch_id = (By.ID,"search-customers")
    txtButton = (By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(), 'Ask Question')]")

def click(self, webelement):
    #self._driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", webelement)
    el = self._wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(webelement))
    # self._highlight_element(el, "green")
    el.click()

class MAIN:
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = driver
        self.click = click
        self._wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)

def main():
    MAIN().driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72478144/convert-a-tuple-into-a-custom-string")
    MAIN().click(MAIN(), SearchCustomerLocators.txtButton)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

---

Answering the question about the significance of the asterisk:

See PEP 448
https://peps.python.org/pep-0448/

Some examples to try:
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_tuples_unpack.asp

Comment: Yes, after removing that it worked fine, i want to understand what is the significance of the '*' ?

Comment: @Learner I updated the end of the answer to help explain the significance of the '*'.